# Is this sentence correct?: "I can leave a little irresponsible image on the people's who assign the job, mind."

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-meaning

I'm trying to improve my English as soon as I can. According to the online English level exams, my English level is between B1 and B2. I want to upgrade it to C1. Therefore, I write a diary every day. Also, each day I'm trying to write more complex sentences. While I was trying some sentences like that, I couldn't be sure of the sentence I made.

Basically, I just want to say: "I can leave a little irresponsible image on the people's minds.". Then I want to write a little detail about people: "people who assign the job".

My sentence:
I can leave a little irresponsible image on the people's who assign the job, mind.

In here, I am not sure at 2 points. The first one is "people's", and the second one is ",mind". Should I use comma(,) before "mind"?

Can you please help me? Your help will be really valuable for me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A sentence ending in ", mind" is likely to be understood as the interjection ["mind you"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mind-you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, "I can leave a little irresponsible image on the people's minds" is an awkward sentence. Is there a different way to phrase this so that the context is more clear? Because as a native speaker, I can only try to understand through making assumptions based on key words, like are you trying to say "I don't want people to think I am irresponsible" or are you saying "I want to leave a bit of an irresponsible image of myself" so as to leave the impression that you aren't uptight?

I will compliment you on the rest of your writing, however, as all of your previous paragraphs were very understandable.

Answer (score 0):

"...on the people's who assign the job mind" no good.

Maybe: "...on the minds of the people who assign the job"